# awscli getting started error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, python-2.7

I'd already asked this on the AWS official forum on Jan-2 but not any reply. So, I m posting it here again so that I can get the error fixed.

---

I installed awscli as stated in this page http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html

And the following is the installation details:

```
millisami at millisami in ~/Code/face_tester on design ✹
± which python                                                                            
/usr/local/bin/python
millisami at millisami in ~/Code/face_tester on design ✹
± python --version                                                                        
Python 2.7.3
millisami at millisami in ~/Code/face_tester on design ✹
± pip install awscli --upgrade                                                            
Requirement already up-to-date: awscli in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: botocore>=0.4.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore-0.4.1-py2.7.egg (from awscli)
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.2.0-py2.7.egg (from awscli)
Requirement already up-to-date: argparse>=1.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/argparse-1.2.1-py2.7.egg (from awscli)
Requirement already up-to-date: requests>=0.12.1,<1.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-0.14.2-py2.7.egg (from botocore>=0.4.0->awscli)
Requirement already up-to-date: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.1-py2.7.egg (from botocore>=0.4.0->awscli)
Cleaning up...
millisami at millisami in ~/Code/face_tester on design ✹
± aws help                                                                                                                      
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/share/python/aws", line 15, in <module>
    import awscli.clidriver
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    import botocore.base
ImportError: No module named botocore.base
millisami at millisami in ~/Code/face_tester on design1 ↵ ✹
```

Since installing the pip its successful, but why that *botocore* is being reported no such file??

Answer (score 73):

Try this command

```
sudo pip install awscli --force-reinstall --upgrade
```

Comment: I was having the same problem and this solved it for me.

Comment: Same problem but didn't work. I get the same error after I run this as I did before.

Comment: Please mark this as the ANSWER @Frank B. are all the packages up to date sudo aptitude update rather than apt-get update? also check python and pip individually.

Comment: Although now I get `Cannot uninstall 'docutils'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.`

Answer (score 4):

I've been having the same problem with similar boto dependencies.  I basically ran `sudo apt-get install awscli` on an AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance and it was totally broken out of the box.

After scratching around for hours, the following seems to have done t'trick:

```
sudo pip install boto --upgrade
sudo pip install boto3 --upgrade
sudo pip install iso8601
sudo pip install sqlalchemy
```

Typing `aws` on the command line after running these commands produced the expected "Usage: ..." message as opposed to a Python stacktrace.

I hope this is helpful to someone else too!

Answer (score 1):

```
brew install awscli
```

If you are using Mac OS. It's working for Sierra

Comment: The pip install didn't solve my problem, forcing the brew version did.

Comment: Same problem but didn't work. I get the same error after I run this as I did before.

Comment: brew upgrade awscli

Comment: Can you get MacOs instances in AWS?

Comment: Might need to run `source ~/.bashrc` (or applicable bash file) after you install with brew.

Answer (score 1):

Dont forget to configure the awscli tool after install:

```
brew install awscli
```

or

```
pip install awscli
```

then

```
aws configure
```

I had to also:

```
pip uninstall boto3
pip install boto3=={correct version}
```

"awscli 1.11.166 has requirement botocore==1.7.24"

Answer (score 0):

I did have the same issue but upgrading awscli via pip/pip3 didn't work for me. The root cause of the issue is basically a conflict between 2 different awscli. Once installed via `apt-get install awscli` and one installed via `pip3 insstall awscli`.  To solve the issue, I removed thee awscli installed in via apt-get. Doing so will remove the aws binary from /usr/bin/aws so just created a soft link from /usr/loca/bin/aws.