# Error when install AWSCLI to Arduino Yun board

Tags: amazon-web-services, arduino, pip, aws-cli, arduino-yun

I try using pip install awscli on the arduino yun kernel but I get the following error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.0.2-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.0.2-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 299, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.0.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 359, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.0.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 576, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.0.2-py2.7.egg/pip/download.py", line 809, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.0.2-py2.7.egg/pip/download.py", line 648, in unpack_http_url
    hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.0.2-py2.7.egg/pip/download.py", line 870, in _download_http_url
    _download_url(resp, link, content_file, hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.0.2-py2.7.egg/pip/download.py", line 594, in _download_url
    hashes.check_against_chunks(downloaded_chunks)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.0.2-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/hashes.py", line 46, in check_against_chunks
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.0.2-py2.7.egg/pip/download.py", line 566, in written_chunks
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.0.2-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/ui.py", line 139, in iter
    for x in it:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.0.2-py2.7.egg/pip/download.py", line 555, in resp_read
    decode_content=False):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.0.2-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 344, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.0.2-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 301, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.0.2-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 54, in read
    self.__callback(self.__buf.getvalue())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.0.2-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/controller.py", line 275, in cache_response
    self.serializer.dumps(request, response, body=body),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.0.2-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/serialize.py", line 87, in dumps
    ).encode("utf8"),
MemoryError
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: ``MemoryError`` Your board doesn't seem to have enough memory to run pip (it never hits AWS CLI code).

Comment: Here you will find the answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/27884718/705293
Please check